# Wrong path in nginx to static page

Tags: python, django, nginx, static-pages

Although I have the application in django, I want to set up a static page.  Using nginx. But I get an error:

`[alert] 100983#0: *439266 "/path_to_page_on_server/press_page.htmlindex.html" is not a directory,`

Here is my url:
`url(r'^press/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='press_page.html'), name='press')`

Here is my config in nginx include:

`location /press/ {
    alias /path_to_page_on_server/press_page.html;
}`

I would like to under `/press/` have page `press_page.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `nginx`, your `index` value is set as `index.html` hence it is being appened to the `alias`-ed location.

You need to specify the `index` to your custom file, and also drop the file reference in `alias`:

```
location /press/ {
    alias /path_to_page_on_server/;
    index press_page.html index.html;
}
```

The last `index.html` is just a fallback, you can drop/replace it if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now my path in error.log lopks like `/path_to_page_on_server/press_page.htmlpress_page.html`. Double `press_page.html`. I removed also `index.html`.

Comment: Aren't you using `nginx` only? Does the request route to `django` also? Whats your actual `/path_to_page_on_server/`?

Comment: sorry I made mistake, everything is perfect. thanks a lot, you made my weekend :)

Comment: @user9192656 No problem. Enjoy your weekend :)